# I have some data in a text file, how should I parse the document that I will only get the value of 'isakm' and 'esp'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
eth                          frames:27 bytes:5286
  ip                         frames:27 bytes:5286
    udp                      frames:11 bytes:2054
      isakm                  frames:11 bytes:2054
    esp                      frames:16 bytes:3232
```

I am writing a python script for it:

```
data = open('data.txt','r')
print(data.read())
```

Comment: How is `esp` and `isakm` defined? Those particular strings? Lines with with that spacing? Is it always line oriented? Once you define precisely what you are looking for, it will be easier for others to help you. It will also be easier for you to see how to solve this.

Comment: eth is something which has ip, ip has udp,udp has isakm also esp is a distinct value so I only want to extract value of isakm and esp.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a regex phrase that would suite your case, if the data is always the same it's pretty easy because you can make assumptions about the spaces length, etc...

Comment: the data is not the same always.:(

Answer (score 0):

Given your example input, you can extract the data following certain fixed delimited values like so:

```
tests={'esp','isakm'}   
with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split()
        if data[0] in tests:
            print(data[1:])
```

Prints:

```
['frames:11', 'bytes:2054']
['frames:16', 'bytes:3232']
```

This ignores the leading spaces that may be meaningful. However, it is unclear from your questions if the spaces are meaningful to your use.